# How to extract a particular string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wonder the best way one could look for a specific phrase in a string and then take everything after it and store that in a new variable. For example in case:

```
var input= "123|ABC S|peter s@xyz.com!!234|George K|george.k@xyz.com";
```

expected output is:

```
peter s@xyz.com,george.k@xyz.com
```

I have tried that code:

```
var input= "123|ABC S|peter s@xyz.com!!234|George K|george.k@xyz.com"; 
var result = input.match(/[a-z]+/gi);
document.write(result);
```

Comment: If the input string will be in same format, split it and use.
var input= "123|ABC S|peter s@xyz.com!!234|George K|george.k@xyz.com"; 
input = input.split('|'),
console.log(input[2],input[4])

Comment: I have to extract only email part of string: peter s@xyz.com,george.k@xyz.com . can you suggest with sample code .

Comment: var input= "123|ABC S|peter s@xyz.com!!234|George K|george.k@xyz.com"; input = input.split('|'), console.log(input[2],input[4]) ouptut of this code is peter s@xyz.com!!234george.k@xyz.com  expected is:peter s@xyz.com,george.k@xyz.com

Answer (score 0):

To extract only emails from input string, try this

```
var input= "123|ABC S|peter s@xyz.com!!234|George K|george.k@xyz.com"; 
var result1 = input.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+ [a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
var result = input.match(/((\d*)+ [a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
document.write(result1 + "," + result);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqp73jdL/)

Comment: Can you please explain this match(input.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi); expected out put is: peter s@xyz.com,george.k@xyz.com  and this code result is s@xyz.com,george.k@xyz.com. Thanks i am geeting exact output can you explain this (input.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi); why regex yiu have added two times.

Comment: check my updated code you can get exact output as what you want

Comment: Yess, i am getting exact output  thanks,  I am trying to understand regex you have used .

Comment: Where is the option for mark to answer , i am using it 1st time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `String.Prototype.split` for this.

```js
var input= "123|ABC S|peter s@xyz.com!!234|George K|george.k@xyz.com";
var users=input.split('!!');
var output='';
users.forEach(function(d, i){
  details = d.split('|');
  output+=details[details.length - 1];
  if(i!==(users.length-1)) 
    output+=','
  }
)
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Can you please explain this part : users.forEach(function(d, i){
  details = d.split('|');
  output+=details[details.length - 1];
  if(i!==(users.length-1)) 
    output+=','
  }

Comment: Please see documentation of `split` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split and  `forEach` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach. It will iterate over all the elements and obtain the email by splitting with | as separator and append it to the output variable